# Time Ordering of Multiple pandas DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a `DataFrame` with an identifier and timestamp columns:

```
DF1:

id    visited
 X    2019-01-07T01:23:45.678
 X    2019-01-08T01:23:45.678
 Y    2019-01-08T03:44:54.789
```

And a separate DataFrame with similar attributes:

```
DF2:

id    visited
 X    2019-01-01T05:23:45.678
 Y    2019-01-08T06:44:54.789
 Y    2019-01-09T09:11:23.476
 Z    2019-01-03T08:12:12.678
```

**How can the first DataFrame (DF1) be filtered for only those rows where the timestamp is before the timestamp in the second DataFrame (DF2) for the corresponding `id` column?**

The resulting dataset would be:

```
id    visited
 Y    2019-01-08T03:44:54.789
```

Note: the `X` entries are filtered out because the timestamp in DF2 is before the timestamp in DF1 (not after).

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `merge_asof`

```
df2['Have']=True
s=pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values('visited'),df2.sort_values('visited'),on='visited',by='id',direction = 'forward')
  id                 visited  Have
0  X 2019-01-07 01:23:45.678   NaN
1  X 2019-01-08 01:23:45.678   NaN
2  Y 2019-01-08 03:44:54.789  True
#s=s[s.Have].copy()
```

Comment: Can you add explanation?

Answer (score 2):

First, rename the 'visited' column from DF2 to 'visited_2'. Then merge the two data frames on the id. Finally, select data with timestamp 'visited' before 'visited_2' and keep the columns you want.

```
DF2.rename(columns={'visited': 'visited_2'}, inplace=True)
DF = pd.merge(DF1, DF2, on=['id'])
DF.loc[DF['visited'] < DF['visited_2'], ['id', 'visited']]
```